# atomic arguments order of execution in C

Tags: c, atomic

I am trying to work with the stdatomic.h functions, specifically atomic_flag_test_and_set. I am not seeing any errors, but want to know if what I am doing is always safe. I have a struct like the following:

```
typedef struct Mystruct {
    int somedata;
    atomic_flag flag;
} Mystruct;
```

Later, when I create a mystruct and use its instance of the flag, I do so like this:

```
if(atomic_flag_test_and_set(&mystructInstance->flag)) {
    // do something
}
```

Is the evaluation of `&mystructInstance->flag` always completed before the check for the atomic operation? I would assume so since it should be one processor instruction (or something that emulates one processor instruction), but I want to make sure.

Comment: The arguments to a function are always evaluated before the function is called.

Comment: How could it be otherwise? What would you pass to the function if the expression weren't evaluated? C doesn't have lazy evaluation.

Comment: Thank you. I read recently about the alloca system call which can't be entered as an argument into the function because it is moving the stack pointer. I recognize that is a very special case. Thank you for validating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the evaluation of `&mystructInstance->flag` always completed before the check for the atomic operation?

The answer to this question can be found in the section on "Function calls" in the C standard.

> **6.5.2.2 Function calls**
>   ...
>   4. An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. **In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument.**

Also note that if a function takes more than one parameter, the order of evaluation of the arguments passed to it is *unspecified*. This also is mentioned in the same section in the standard.

> 10.There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call. Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise speciﬁcally sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function.

Comment: Good cite to the standard. It's also a good idea to point out `6.5.2.2(p10)` that while the arguments are evaluated, the order in which they are evaluated is indeterminate. So in `f(a(), b(), c()) {...}`, there is no guarantee which order `b, c, a` will be evaluated in.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Thank you. Updated the answer with your input.

Comment: And something more that "order being unspecified" means that the evaluations of *distinct* arguments may interleave.